# Convert snapshot from firebase to model class

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

**I'm trying to create a `Future` method of return type `AddressModel` fetched from `Firestore`. But I'm stuck. **

**AddressModel Class:**

```
class AddressModel{
  int pinCode,contactNum;
  String fullName,apartment,city,state;
  String? area;
  String? landmark;

  AddressModel({
    required this.pinCode,
    required this.contactNum,
    required this.fullName,
    required this.apartment,
    required this.city,
    required this.state,
    this.area,
    this.landmark,
  });

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'pinCode': pinCode,
      'contactNum': contactNum,
      'fullName': fullName,
      'apartment': apartment,
      'area': area,
      'landmark': landmark,
      'city': city,
      'state': state,
    };
  }

  factory AddressModel.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return AddressModel(
      pinCode: map['pinCode'] as int,
      contactNum: map['contactNum'] as int,
      fullName: map['fullName'] as String,
      apartment: map['apartment'] as String,
      area: map['area'] as String,
      landmark: map['landmark'] as String,
      city: map['city'] as String,
      state: map['state'] as String,
    );
  }
}
```

**Future Method:**

```
Future<AddressModel?> getAddress(BuildContext context)async{
    try{
      DocumentSnapshot snapshot = await _fireStore.collection("users").doc(currentUser!.uid).get();
      
      //---------------Stuck Here----------------//
      
    }on FirebaseException catch(e){
      showSnackBar(context, e.code.toString());
      return null;
    }
  }
```

**Firestore Document:**
[image: demo]

**Fixed it:** (thank you all for your help)

```
QuerySnapshot snapshot = await _fireStore.collection("users").where("uId",isEqualTo: currentUser!.uid).get();

      if(snapshot.docs.isNotEmpty){
        return AddressModel.fromMap(snapshot.docs[0]['address']);
      }
      return null;
```

Comment: Any error you are facing? Address inside your firestore collection is a Map, It should be part of the parent class

example:

User{
Map<String, dynamic> address;
}

Comment: Use `withConverter`, check [the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#custom_objects).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DocumentSnapshot has a propety called data, so use

```
snapshot.data // this will return the object in type Map<String, dynamic>
```

and then just use you AddressModel.fromMap to parse

will be something like this, if you want do see in debug:

```
Map<String, dynamic> response = snapshot.data;
AddressModel addressModel = AddressModel.fromMap(response);
return addressModel;
```

you can join all in one too:

```
return AddressModel.fromMap(snapshot.data)
```

you can see the doc in pub firebase_firestore:
https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase/latest/firebase_firestore/DocumentSnapshot-class.html

Comment: thank you, it worked but I had to make some adjustments. Like changing the `DocumentSnapshot` to `QuerySnapshot` .